# Detecting divs with the save calls name using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

```
elm = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="text-[18px] text-[#556a7a] table-chart"]').click()
```

This code will press a button, but there is a lot more of this button in the save screen with the save class name. And when i run this i it will press the first button, how do i make it so it will press each one and pass on to the second one.

HTML code:

```
<div class="text-[18px] text-[#556a7a] table-chart" data-id="81777" data-name="تیرآهن&nbsp;12&nbsp;ذوب آهن&nbsp;&nbsp;12 متری&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;IPE&nbsp;تهران" data-code="0392">
                            <i class="icon-CHART cursor-pointer"></i>
                        </div>
```

[this is how the buttons look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJJPy.png)

Comment: Please edit your question with relevant html and mentioned which button to click.

Comment: You can choose one of other ways how to find button and click it
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KunduK sorry for providing a low amount of information, i hope the edits i have made will help you figure the answer out.